# how to share big photo of link in facebook and google plus

Tags: facebook

I have a photo gallery site

How to share the big picture of facebook

current share : !
[image: all api]

i love like this page of site HomeDSGN :

[image]
https://www.facebook.com/HomeDSGN?ref=br_tf

Comment: doesn't that depend on the size of the picture in the `og:image` metatag?

Comment: @tattvamasi not worked with og:image meta tag .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**my problem very nice solved ^_^**

i change `name` to `property`

```
<meta name="og:image" content="http://www.sooran.com/public/images/upload/6208/">
```

**good code** :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sooran.com/public/images/upload/6208/">
```

for solve this problem in **google plus** pls see this link ^_^:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25581/how-does-google-plus-select-an-image-from-a-shared-link